# Finding convergence through the comparison theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

In class we have been studying the comparison theorem to determine whether a integral is convergent or divergent. But the method of this theorem escapes me. I know that in the given function i must find a g(x) such that $f(x)$ greater than or equal to $g(x)$ which is greater than or equal to $0.$

Given the example $$\int_{ (1, \infty)} \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}} dx $$, how would i use the comparison theorem to determine if this integral is convergent or divergent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^4-x\leq x^4$ for $x\in[1,\infty]$ so that $$\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}}\geq\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4}}=\frac{x+1}{x^2}.$$ Argue that the integral of the smaller expression diverges and use the comparison test to conclude the result.